# Refactoring Large Codebehinds - Repository pattern and Extension methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, refactoring, repository-pattern

I was hoping someone could help clarify my options regarding refactoring methods from code-behinds from ASP.NET webforms pages.

As background, we have spent some time recently implementing the repository pattern in both a generic and non generic sense, which has enabled us to move a lot of the DAL methods out of the codebehinds, which is great.

What I'm struggling to finalise, is a sensible approach to moving application logic methods out of the codebehinds which specific focus on the repository/DAL and how best to structure the BL classes.

Here are the two options I am considering at present:

1.Create a Business Logic class per codebehind and from this, expose
        methods like `getProject(int id)` which would behind the scenes,
        access a repository instance of `repo.GetById(int id)`

The benefit of this as far as I can see would be the following:

- seperate app logic from the codebehinds, allowing them to be simple
- allowing testable methods at the BLL (with some tweaking), kind of synonymous with controller classes in MVC (this is still webforms though)
- Doesn't expose the repository directly

The downside would be:

- A lot of wrapper methods in the BLL which don't really do anything
  besides hide the repository methods

2.Write extension methods on my entity types, e.g. `Project.getUsers()` which would access a repository instance method  allowing BL to be stored without the need for a specific BLL class, thereby reducing the duplication of the wrapper methods in each BL class.

The benefit of this would be:

- No need to have a BL as such, storing methods with their entity type
- Less wrapper methods, as there wouldn't be a need for `ProjectBL.getUsers(projectid)` and `UserBL.getUsers(projectid)` which both call `repo.getProjectUsers(projectid)` behind the scenes, simple `Project.getUsers()` from both codebehinds

The downside of this as far as I can tell:

- If I introduce new types in the future, e.g. 'SubProject' `getUsers()` needs to be re-implimented
- I'm not too keen on extension methods in general and not sure if this is the right place to use them!

I'm a little unsure which is 'better' practice, or if I've missed a better option all together. It may be worth knowing that initially the repository was being instantiated in the codebehind and accessed directly, but as I understand things, this is not ideal as we risk returning things like IQueryable from the repository and making DAL methods which can be manipulated in codebehind to produce inconsistent results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model I have found to be most effective with ASP.NET Webforms is the bind/unbind pattern. In this pattern, the only things you implement in the codebehind itself are event handlers (which will call back to more abstracted, logic-heavy methods in a BLL of some sort) and one method each to transfer data from (Bind) and to (Unbind) an instance of a domain object or DTO.

By structuring the codebehind in this way, the codebehind class becomes concerned only with the interop between logic and presentation, and so becomes quite thin in most cases. The data it will deal with will be primarily primitives and the DTO, and it will not require any knowledge of the DAL (at least, individual page codebehinds won't; you may set up your master page or a base class for your codebehinds to have DAL-touching methods common to wide swaths of your site, basically making this base class your Controller layer in code).

One other thing to keep in mind is that, depending on structure, it can be very simple to unit-test your codebehind classes. You can even TDD them, to a point; the declaration of basic GUI elements in the markup (and their object representations in the codebehind) is still best left to the IDE, but a public codebehind class with publicly-accessible members can be easily instantiated in a unit test, and the public methods exercised.

Comment: I think as you say, this is where I'm heading, but my concern is to ensure that the BLL is not repeating work by say making one BLL class per codebehind and needing to re-impliment methods over and all which are simply wrapper functions around the DAL.
In such an implementation, how would you structure the BLL classes? say I have a Users.aspx, Projects.aspx and Admin.aspx page for example, would you envisage a UsersBL.cs class to be instantiated from the codebehind? with all the 'users' BL methods in it, calling to DAL methods? and a separate BL class for the Projects.aspx page?

Comment: Generally I would encourage use of a centralized Repository, with a single front door for persistence Save(), that can accept ANY domain class or DTO you wanted to persist. An ORM is invaluable in a circumstance like this. If this is not feasible given existing design, try injecting various "save", "validate" and other BL-heavy methods from a controller into the codebehind. As far as how to structure it exactly, I couldn't tell you specifically, but try to build an inheritance hierarchy either in the controller or codebehind layers, which will allow you to move common code up to base classes.

Answer (score 0):

@KeithS I'm going to mark this one as accepted as no one else seems to have any suggestions! In case you curious I've opted to go more for the second approach, basically in my application I have some logical 'sections' such as 'Projects' or 'ApprovalForms' and I've gone with creating a single BL class per section rather than one per codebehind.

This does mean the class can contain methods which can be a bit varied (not a single purpose), but it does prevent me having tons of classes with basically the same method accessed from a different context. It is forcing me to write wrapper methods around the repository methods which feels a bit W.E.T. but it does mean that I can provide a common method for returning data to the front end, reducing the chance of having differing implementations.